# Redirect Immediately after countdown completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a quick question in regards to redirecting to a the page set after
the countdown completes. Here is the code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#continue').countTo({
        interval: 1000,
        startNumber: 5,
        endNumber: 0,
        onLoop: function (self, current, loop) {
            $(self).text('Wait: ' + current);
        },
        onFinish: function (self, current, loop) {
            self.removeClass('red').addClass('green');
            $(self).html('continue').on('click', function () {
                top.location = '<?php echo $data['url']?>';
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It's presumed that the onlick needs to be changed, but I am not sure to what, and how to implement it from there. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

For anyone else who comes across this the correct answer is:
Take this code:

```
            onFinish: function (self, current, loop) {
            self.removeClass('red').addClass('green');
            $(self).html('continue').on('click', function () {
                top.location = '<?php echo $data['url']?>';
            });
```

and it becomes this:

```
            onFinish: function (self, current, loop) {
            self.removeClass('red').addClass('green');

                top.location = '<?php echo $data['url']?>';

        }
```

Comment: `countTo` some sort of plugin?

Comment: It's basically a script to redirect someone on an ad page after the counter has been displayed for "X" seconds. Right now, it displays for 5 seconds and you have to click "continue". Would like to have it just redirect immediately.

Comment: Move the location outside the click event?

Comment: Thanks Karl-Andre! That worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You just want it to happen when the countdown is done, no click? Just remove the handler...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#continue').countTo({
      interval: 1000,
      startNumber: 5,
      endNumber: 0,
      onLoop: function (self, current, loop) {
          $(self).text('Wait: ' + current);
      },
      onFinish: function (self, current, loop) {
          top.location = '<?php echo $data['url']?>';
      }
  });
```

});

Comment: Yep, that's the answer I was gonna give.